Issues with threading and hotkeys using pynput in Python (Infinite Loop and Responsiveness)
I'm trying to use the pynput library to listen for hotkeys and start a thread when the F12 key is pressed. The thread prints a message in an infinite loop to the console. Pressing ESC should stop the application. My Example class extends Thread and overrides the run method.
src/index.py
import pynput
from lib.listener import HotkeyListener

if __name__ == "__main__":
    on_press = HotkeyListener()
    listener = pynput.keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press.on_press, suppress=True)
    listener.run()

listener.py
from .Example import Example
import pynput

class HotkeyListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.example = Example()

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f12:
            print("Starting Thread...")
            self.example.start()

        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
            self.example.join()
            print("Exiting application...")
            return False  # Stop listener

example.py
from threading import Thread
from .delay import rand_sleep

class Example(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("Hello, I am an Example :) ?")  # This message appears in the console
            rand_sleep(1, 2)

Problem:
When the F12 key is pressed, the thread starts and enters an infinite loop, printing messages to the console. This causes the application to not respond to other hotkeys, like ESC, to stop the execution.
Questions:

How can I make my application respond to other hotkeys while the thread is running?
What is the correct way to manage threads in this scenario to avoid the infinite loop that freezes the computer?
Is there a more efficient or correct way to implement this hotkey listening functionality with threading?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
@EDIT
After @jupiterbjy's response, I arrived at the following solution (now it works as expected!), but there's a runtime error when I try to create it again by pressing the hotkey. The thread no longer exists and can only be started once:
class Example(Thread):
    def __init__(self, event: Event) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.event = event

    def run(self):
        counter: Number = 0
        while not self.event.is_set():
            print("Hello, I am an Example :)? ")
            rand_sleep(1, 2)
            counter += 1
            if counter > 5:
                self.event.set()
                # RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
                
class HotkeyListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thread_event = threading.Event()
        self.example = Example(self.thread_event)

    def on_press(self, key):
        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f12:
            print("---------------------", self.example)
            # --------------------- <Example(Thread-1, stopped 9676)>
            self.example.start()

        if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
            self.thread_event.set()
            self.example.join()
            print("Exiting application...")
            return False  # Stop listener


Not much of importance since naming already explains but I think you forgot delay.py! otherwise this is one of cleanest I saw last entire week.

@jupiterbjy Yes, but it only adds a delay; however, it doesn't work.

Yeah obviously this doesn't - join doesn't kill thread, but wait for it to stop itself. I'm writing answer as we speak, kinda curious what your actual intention behind the question is. (i.e. making a daemon, or running something in pararell, etc)

Honestly, I don't understand much about the subject, I don't know the difference, but I would like to make a hotkey that pauses immediately, and I read some things about daemon so I put that in the code. @jupiterbjy

Ah I see, that case you don't need to subclass Thread, just using Thread itself should do. I'll write answer in that direction

maybe instead of while True you should use while self.running: and set self.running = True when you start thread, and later set self.running = False when you press ESC. Other method is to use queue to send message "quit" to thread and thread should use if not queue.empty(): if queue.get() == "quit": break inside while True to exit this loop.

btw: if you plan to start threat again and again then you have to create self.example = Example() again and again.

@furas Yes, I wish to do this in the future, but wouldn't it already be created? Is it completely destroyed?

when you stop thread then you can't run it again - you have to create again Example()

Yes, I updated the question about this, but I should create a kind of 'if' to achieve this, but I'm not finding the correct method. @furas

To quote from document:

join(timeout=None)
Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or until the optional timeout occurs.

This is used to wait until thread is stopped, not to stop the thread. Hence your infinite loop in Example class never had chance to stop.
To quote from Trio Documentation about threading:

Cancellation is a tricky issue here, because neither Python nor the operating systems it runs on provide any general mechanism for cancelling an arbitrary synchronous function running in a thread. This function will always check for cancellation on entry, before starting the thread. But once the thread is running, there are two ways it can handle being cancelled:

If cancellable=False, the function ignores the cancellation and keeps going, just like if we had called sync_fn synchronously. This is the default behavior.
If cancellable=True, then this function immediately raises Cancelled. In this case the thread keeps running in background – we just abandon it to do whatever it’s going to do, and silently discard any return value or errors that it raises.


So, from these we can learn that there's no good way to terminate infinite-loop running in thread.
Instead, we use Threading.Event.
import threading
import random
import time

import pynput


def thread_print(*arg, **kwargs):
    """Print with thread id"""

    print(f"[T:{threading.get_ident():6}]", *arg, **kwargs)


def func_for_thread(event: threading.Event):
    """Function to be ran on thread"""

    thread_print("Thread started")

    while not event.is_set():
        time.sleep(1)
        thread_print(random.randint(1, 10))

    thread_print("Thread finished")


def main():
    thread_event = threading.Event()

    # Create 5 threads, but don't start yet
    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=func_for_thread, args=(thread_event,)) for _ in range(5)
    ]
    threads_started = False

    # main thread will start listening for key press
    with pynput.keyboard.Events() as events:

        # for each incoming keyboard event:
        for event in events:

            # change match-case to if-elif-else for python < 3.10
            match event.key:

                case pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
                    print("ESC pressed! Stopping all threads!")
                    thread_event.set()

                    # wait for thread to stop gracefully
                    for thread in threads:
                        thread.join()

                    break

                case pynput.keyboard.Key.space:
                    if threads_started:
                        continue

                    threads_started = True

                    print(f"SPACE pressed! Starting all threads!")

                    # start threads
                    for thread in threads:
                        thread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

SPACE pressed! Starting all threads!
[T: 25216] Thread started
[T: 25796] Thread started
[T: 26688] Thread started
[T:  4216] Thread started
[T: 26480] Thread started
[T: 25216] 10
[T: 25796] 1
[T: 26688] 9
[T:  4216] 3
[T: 26480] 9
[T: 25216] 6
[T: 25796] 10
[T: 26688] 3
[T:  4216] 10
[T: 26480] 2
ESC pressed! Stopping all threads!
[T: 25216] 4
[T: 25216] Thread finished
[T: 25796] 3
[T: 25796] Thread finished
[T: 26688] 7
[T: 26688] Thread finished
[T:  4216] 9
[T:  4216] Thread finished
[T: 26480] 6
[T: 26480] Thread finished

Since what you actually wanted to do is creating hotkey that stoppes immediately, this should be sufficient. Subclassing Thread is overkill for that!

EDIT:
To expand further for restartability, and independant control I added convenience wrapper class.
import threading
import random
import time

import pynput
from typing import Callable


class RestartableThread:
    def __init__(self, target: Callable[[threading.Event, ...], ...], *args, **kwargs):
        """Create a tiny thread manager that can be restarted.

        Args:
            target (Callable): A function/method to run on thread.
                Must accept `threading.Event` as first argument.

            args (tuple, optional): Argument for target. Defaults to ().
            kwargs (dict, optional): Argument for target. Defaults to {}.
        """

        self.target: Callable[[threading.Event, ...], ...] = target
        self.thread: threading.Thread | None = None
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.args = (self.event, *args)
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    @property
    def is_running(self):
        """Check if thread is running"""
        return self.thread is not None and self.thread.is_alive()

    @property
    def is_stopping(self):
        """Check if thread is stopping"""
        return self.event.is_set()

    def run(self):
        """Start thread. Doesn't do anything if already running"""

        # ignore if already running
        if self.is_running:
            return

        # make sure thread is stopped before starting new one
        self.join()

        # create new thread & start
        self.thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.target, args=self.args, kwargs=self.kwargs
        )
        self.thread.start()

    def join(self):
        """Wait for thread to stop gracefully"""

        if self.thread is None:
            return

        self.thread.join()
        self.event.clear()
        # ^ also clear event so we can restart thread

    def stop(self):
        """Signal thread to stop"""
        self.event.set()


def thread_print(*arg, **kwargs):
    """Print with thread id"""

    print(f"[T:{threading.get_ident():6}]", *arg, **kwargs)


def func_a_for_thread(event: threading.Event, *args, **kwargs):
    """Function to be ran on thread"""

    thread_print("Thread started")

    while not event.is_set():
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        thread_print("Func A running with args:", args, kwargs)

    thread_print("Thread finished")


# Your codes in Thread subclass goes here!
class SomeClass:
    # skipping init

    def func_b_for_thread(self, event: threading.Event, *args, **kwargs):
        """Function to be ran on thread"""

        thread_print("Thread started")

        while not event.is_set():
            time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
            thread_print("Func B running with args:", args, kwargs)

        thread_print("Thread finished")


def main():
    # create threads
    thread_a = RestartableThread(func_a_for_thread, args=("arg1", "arg2"))

    some_instance = SomeClass()
    thread_b = RestartableThread(some_instance.func_b_for_thread, args=("arg3", "arg4"))

    # main thread will start listening for key press
    with pynput.keyboard.Events() as events:

        # for each incoming keyboard event:
        for event in events:

            if event.key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:
                print("ESC pressed! Stopping all threads!")
                thread_a.stop()
                thread_b.stop()

                # wait for thread to stop gracefully
                thread_a.join()
                thread_b.join()

                break

            # some keys don't have char attribute
            if not hasattr(event.key, "char"):
                continue

            match event.key.char:
                case "a":
                    if not thread_a.is_running:
                        print("Starting thread A")
                        thread_a.run()

                case "b":
                    if not thread_b.is_running:
                        print("Starting thread B")
                        thread_b.run()

                case "c":
                    if thread_a.is_running and not thread_a.is_stopping:
                        print("Stopping thread A!")
                        thread_a.stop()

                case "d":
                    if thread_b.is_running and not thread_b.is_stopping:
                        print("Stopping thread B!")
                        thread_b.stop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Starting thread A
[T: 30628] Thread started
Starting thread B
[T: 28796] Thread started
[T: 28796] Func B running with args: ('arg3', 'arg4') {}
[T: 30628] Func A running with args: ('arg1', 'arg2') {}
[T: 28796] Func B running with args: ('arg3', 'arg4') {}
[T: 30628] Func A running with args: ('arg1', 'arg2') {}
[T: 28796] Func B running with args: ('arg3', 'arg4') {}
Stopping thread A!
[T: 28796] Func B running with args: ('arg3', 'arg4') {}
[T: 30628] Func A running with args: ('arg1', 'arg2') {}
[T: 30628] Thread finished
Stopping thread B!
Starting thread A
[T: 11376] Thread started
[T: 28796] Func B running with args: ('arg3', 'arg4') {}
[T: 28796] Thread finished
ESC pressed! Stopping all threads!
[T: 11376] Func A running with args: ('arg1', 'arg2') {}
[T: 11376] Thread finished

ESC pressed! Stopping all threads!


I'll updated my question showing examples that I arrived at with your answer, but without success. Perhaps I forgot some point.

@Collaxd aye! and would love it to be detailed enough - such as Ability to restart, multiple threads, etc

@Collaxd Yup this should do I think.. Your Thread subclass approach is not recommended for such usecase, as each Thread is single-use only. So we need some way to recreate Thread everytime we restart it. Change your Example class like SomeClass in edited code so it doesn't inherit from thread - RestartableThread class wrapper will handle the stopping and respawning the thread, abstracting away messy works!

@Collaxd oh I made awful typo in args, change args=(), kwargs={} to *args, **kwargs in class init - passing those as explict tuple and dict is just dumb, yet my sleepy head let that autocompletion pass

Instead of while True: use while self.running: and

set self.running = True inside run() before while
set self.example.running = False when you press ESC

Other problem can be if you want run again thread because it can't be started when you stopped it - you have to create new Example()
Other problem is to run only one thread - you can use self.example = None to inform if thread exists or not.
class Example(Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.running  = True
        while self.running:
            print("Hello, I am an Example :) ?")  # This message appears in the console
            rand_sleep(1, 2)

# --- 

self.example = None  # default value at start

# --- 

if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f12:
    if self.example is None:  # run only one thread
        self.example = Example()
        self.example.start()

if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:            
    if self.example is not None:
        self.example.running = False  # stop loop
        self.example.join()  # wait for end of thread
        self.example = None  # inform that thread was stopped


Other method is to run thread all time and use some variable to pause code
class Example(Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.paused = True
        while True:
            if not self.paused:
                print("Hello, I am an Example :) ?")  # This message appears in the console
                rand_sleep(1, 2)

# ---

self.example = Example()
self.example.start()

# --- 

if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.f12:
    self.example.paused = False

if key == pynput.keyboard.Key.esc:            
    self.example.paused = True

But this still may need self.running to stop thread when you want to exit program
